# List LFS tracked files in pre-receive hook

Tags: gitlab, hook, git-lfs

I am trying to write a git pre-receive hook that rejects LFS files larger than a certain size (among other things).

I am trying to execute `git lfs ls-files -l -s <new-ref-value>` in my script, but it returns

```
2ec20be70bb1be824e124a61eabac40405d60de62c76d263eff9923f18c098ed - binary.dll (63 B)

Could not scan for Git LFS tree: missing object: a405ce05ac78ea1b820d036676831a474ddf8f90
```

I cannot even ignore the error message because it stops after the first file.

I guess that the problem has to do with the fact that the commits have not been "validated" on the remote yet. The frustrating thing is that the information that I need (new file paths + sizes) is accessible since it's printed for the first file.

Is there a way to run the `git lfs ls-files` command with the new ref value successfully at this stage?

Can I obtain the list of the added file paths and sizes in any other way?

EDIT: If that's relevant in any way, the Git server is a GitLab instance in its default configuration.